# Our language when we talk about Mathematica functions

Tags: discussion

The discussion in the comments in two recent `AspectRatio` threads ([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83771/280),[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83779/280)) has highlighted one important aspect of our established way of expressing our thoughts about the *Mathematica* (or Wolfram Language) functions: we tend to use the names of built-in system `Symbol`s instead of the corresponding words of the usual English language. In many cases it allows us to reach wonderful conciseness and exactness of our description at one time. But it also gives a temptation to use names of the `Symbol`s outside of their field of use. A good example is `PlotRange` option.

The confusion between `PlotRange` and "`plot range`" has historical prerequisite: before version 6 there was no `PlotRangePadding` option and `PlotRange` was widely used interchangeably with "`plot range`" because they actually meant the same. Starting from version 6, the situation has changed but in many places in the Documentation we still read statements that were not updated since version 5.

Today `PlotRange` option along with `PlotRangePadding` option determines the range of values of coordinates included inside of the `Frame` of the final graphics (even if it is switched off by `Frame->False`).

The terms "`plot range`" and "`plot area`" were used long time before version 6 came out where the functions `PlotRangePadding` and `ImagePadding` were introduced. At that time the confusion between `PlotRange`, `plot range` and `plot area` was not possible because all of them meant the same: the area on the plot where graphical primitives can potentially be displayed. But now a new user of *Mathematica* faces a problem similar to the chicken and egg problem: the Documentation mixes definitions which are valid for different versions and makes it impossible to formulate in clear words even basic concepts of the language.

For example, what means the term "`plot area`"? The area where graphical primitives can potentially be displayed? But with `PlotRangeClipping->False` the graphical primitives which lie in the area determined by `ImagePadding` option will be shown what is outside of `plot range`.

It is logical that under `PlotRange` we should understand only value of this option, not the complete `plot range`. I feel natural to say that `PlotRangePadding` increases the `plot range` but not the value of the `PlotRange` option which remains the same as can be verified by applying `Options[#, PlotRange]&`. But I am not sure what currently we should understand under "`plot area`". What term should I use if I want to say about the full area where graphical primitives can potentially be displayed (which includes both `PlotRangePadding` and `ImagePadding`)?

I feel that our language when we speak about *Mathematica* should be regularized in some way. What do you think about it?

Comment: Besides the broader scope of the question here, let me note, that the documentation for `AspectRatio` says that it determines the height-to-width of the `PlotRange`, not "plot range", so at the end of the day I agree with you, that the documentation in the strictest sense is not correct.

Comment: Yep, WRI should hire someone to tidy up docs. Documentation is nice but after a closer look it is a mess which will waste your time unless you get a habit to test each statement... which would be a wast of time anyway since documentation should be correct...